# Adding autolayout constraint programmatically turns uiview to black

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, loadview

I need a view controller without xib. There should be a webview with fully filled to the view. For that I've added the following code to loadView method.

```
- (void)loadView {
    CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self setView:view];
//    //create webview
    self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.webview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [view addSubview:self.webview];
    [self.webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.webview setDelegate:self];

    NSDictionary *viewBindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view,_webview);
//    //add constraints
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_webview]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewBindings]];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_webview]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewBindings]];

}
```

But this turns the entire view to black. If I coment `[view addConstraints:...` method calls its showing a green view. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: If you haven't done so already, put a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and then check the frames of your views. Maybe that will give you a clue what could be wrong with your constraints.

Comment: If I put breakepoint in view dicload and check frames the result is like (lldb) po self.view
<UIView: 0x7fe279c60120; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe279c78e40>>
in both cases

Comment: At this point the frame is still `CGRectZero`. Which is why you see a black background. So your constraints are not right. I'm not at my Mac now, so cannot tell you what it should be.

Comment: BTW, why not make the webView your view with `applicationFrame `, and then you probably don't even need autolayout.

Comment: @Koen I need some more controls in the view, so I'm not setting the webview as view controller's view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that the parent view should not set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false. The only view that must set that attribute to false is the one you are applying autolayout to, in this case webView. If you set `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false then you have to add constraints to `view`.

Comment: hoo... thank you.. just setting view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES; solved my problems

Comment: @Johnykutty Happy to help! I would recommend you to keep `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false and add top, bottom, left and right constraints. Then, the view will stretch to the whole screen when you rotate it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the root view of the `UIViewController` manually, maybe that's why it does not work.

My suggestion would be to try this out:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    self.webview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [view addSubview:self.webview];
    [self.webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [self.webview setDelegate:self];

    NSDictionary *viewBindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view,_webview);
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_webview]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewBindings]];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_webview]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewBindings]];
    // put a breakpoint after this line to see the frame of your UIWebView. 
    // It should be the same as the view
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This should work and your `UIWebView` should be full screen. Good luck!